Model Import fails ExpressJS / Sequelize fail?
Hey guys I am building a fullstack website to to learn Express , Sequelize and REST api
I have this model for a post request ``
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const PaymentMethods = sequelize.define("payment_methods", {
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    cardnumber: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    expirydate: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    CVC: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }, {
    timestamps: false
  });

  return PaymentMethods;
};

Then we use it in this file
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
const db = require('../models');

router.post('/payment/updatepaymentmethod', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, cardNumber, expDate, cvc } = req.body;

    // Create a new payment method record in the database
    const newPaymentMethod = await db.PaymentMethods.create({
      email: email,
      cardnumber: cardNumber,
      expirydate: expDate,
      CVC: cvc
    });

    // Return success response
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Payment method updated successfully',
      paymentMethod: newPaymentMethod
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during payment method update:', error);

    // Log the error object for debugging
    console.log(error);

    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: 'Payment method update failed',
      error: error.message
    });
  }
});

module.exports = router;```

Edit here is the index file for the models : 

   ``` 'use strict';
    
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    const process = require('process');
    const basename = path.basename(__filename);
    const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
    const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
    const db = {};
    
    let sequelize;
    if (config.use_env_variable) {
      sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
    } else {
      sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
    }
    
    fs
      .readdirSync(__dirname)
      .filter(file => {
        return (
          file.indexOf('.') !== 0 &&
          file !== basename &&
          file.slice(-3) === '.js' &&
          file.indexOf('.test.js') === -1
        );
      })
      .forEach(file => {
        const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
        db[model.name] = model;
      });
    
    Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
      if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
      }
    });
    
    db.sequelize = sequelize;
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
    
    module.exports = db;


I get this error
"error": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')"
If I change the method to update it still does so.
And the weirdest thing is that I have another request on a different model but with exactly the same structure and it works perfectly fine.
I tried several things to fix it but none of them worked or I ran into stuff I don't really know, like changing the index.js file properties From what I understood the problem is the model importing into my file.
It should allow me to push some data to my database table payment_methods

Exactly the same? It exports a function that’s never called—I don’t see how it could work as-is.

Please show models module

I added the index file for the models

I don't know why you've written your model like that but since you are returning PaymentMethods perhaps db.create() might get you the desired result.
